# The page at about:blank displayed insecure content

Tags: asp.net, html, google-chrome, https

I got the following warning & error by the chrome browser while trying to access my webpage via https.

**Warning:** The page at about:blank displayed insecure content from http://subdomain.name.dns-stuff.com/go.php?sid=mix.

**Error:** Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Should i start worrying?
How can i find where this insecure content comes from?

**UPDATE:** A malicious IFRAME can source in content from web pages that attempt to fingerprint and exploit a browser vulnerability or client/OS vulnerability to cause a drive-by-download. Such IFRAMEs are typically invisible to users.

http://wam.dasient.com/wam/infection_library/917395c589f265fd940fc7cc9b0df341/dns-stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting the hosting provider of mine they managed to find that the webpage was infected. Actually a part of the jquery.js was infected.

Lessons learned.

1. Never download the jquery libraries (or anything) from any place of the web, except the official ones.
2. Keep up to the latest versions via links to the official sites.

Answer (score 0):

The [404 or Not Found error message](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/404_error) is a HTTP standard response code indicating that the client was able to communicate with the server, but the server could not find what was requested.

So when you try to access http://www.dns-stuff.com you will see that the domain is live and returning content however when you try http://www.dns-stuff.com/go.php?sid=mix you will see the 404 error which means the content should return by calling **"go.php?sid=mix"**, is not available and error 404 shows this message. So you just need to know that the content is missing while the server is still responding.

Edited:

According to [Google](http://royal.pingdom.com/2009/05/06/the-5-most-common-http-errors-according-to-google/) Error 404 is the second most occurring error!!

Comment: Would u please provide your actual URL which shows this error? I will try to check in my Sandbox and see. Because I can not find any correlation with your IFRAME related error and 404 error. These two looks separate to me.. unless there is something missing.

Comment: Based on the URL you provided, I checked the fiddler traffic and it shows shows that the content is missing that's why there is 404 error. I don't think there is any reason to worry because the server does not have any content to server as requested.

Comment: Ok, but who added that iframe in my webpage and how? You see it "breaks" the SSL experience to my visitors too...

Comment: I think it is added by the dynamic-dns service you are using. The fact is bad code injected via iframes and it seems dynamic dns is also adding code in  iframe and browser security prompts it to user and protect the code to run. Check internet for dns forwarding and iframe and you will learn more on it.